# How do I set a specific starting number in headings?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a large document that needs splitting into 2 but they need to be used in conjunction with each other, therefore I need the headings 1, 2 & 3 from DOC 1 to follow in DOC 2. 
e.g. DOC 1 starts at Heading 1 (number 1) through to Header 1 (number 6) Header 2 (number 6.10) Header 3 (number 6.10.6) at the end of DOC 1.

*I need DOC 2* to **START** at **Header 1** (*from* number **6**) **Header 2** (number **6.11**) and **Header 3** (number **6.11.1**) and then follow that number incrementing format as it cascades down on DOC 2.
Can you please offer a solution before I lose my sanity, as each time I try to set the headings in DOC 2 the whole document goes wrong!

Many thanks in advance,

TMoore

Answer (score 0):

You should create multilevel list, as follows:

1. Home -> Paragraph -> Multilevel list drop down button -> Define New Multilevel List.... This should open the Define new Multilevel list dialog.
2. In the top left part of the dialog, ensure 1 is selected for Click level to modify.
3. In Number format -> Start at: choose 6. Now your Heading 1 starts from 6.
4. Repeat for Click level to modify: 2 and choose Start at: -> 11.